# "Field Value is not a function" when I try to use the increment feature

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement some simple thumbs up/thumbs down functionality in a react  app using cloud firestore. The app lets users search for movies and give it a thumbs up or down, and then I want to increment the value in my frestore database. When I try to do this I'm given the error "FieldValue is not a function".

Here is my code in the component:

```
 import {db}from './firebase'
    const firebase = require("firebase/firestore");
    const movieDocRef = db.collection("ratings").doc(title);
    const increment = firebase.FieldValue.increment(1);
    movieDocRef.update({thumbsUP: increment})
```

And here is my firebase config file

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");
const config = {
    //my config data all should fine
  };
  

export const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const db = fire.firestore();
```

Would appreciate any help you can give. I've looked at a few similar topics and nothing seems to have resolved this

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using react, I suggest reviewing the documentation for [getting started with Firebase using module bundlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#using-module-bundlers).  Your imports should look more like this when using version 8.0.0 or later of the Firebase SDKs:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore"

const movieDocRef = firebase.firestore().collection("ratings").doc(title);
movieDocRef.update({ thumbsUP: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) })
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I've tried that import method before and still got the error. Just tried it again and got the below error:
×
TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default.a.firestore.FieldValue.increment is not a function.

I have the imports in both my comopnent file and the firebase configuration file.